# How to edit soldier loadout?

Tags: battlefield-1, battlefield-1-beta

I haven't found a way to change my loadout, on the main menu 'soldier' tab is blacked out and there's nothing in 'store'. Can I only configure when I'm in an online match? Battlefield series is known for having odd restrictions, in BF 4 you can't play multiplayer without installing a browser plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the beta, the only way to buy weapons and accessories and to edit your loadout is during a game.

While you are on the respawn screen, you can select a class loadout, then you can use your controls to move inside that loadout and select things like your main weapon, side arm, grenades, tools, etc..

Then you press the *correct button* * to access the sub menu, inside this menu you will find new items you can purchase with your war bonds and you can also select purchased items to spawn with.

The same way applies for vehicles, which is annoying because this means you have to wait for vehicles to be available to be able to customize your loadout.

> *When i say the correct button, you should find that on the lower left side of your screen, i see you are playing on PC, i personally play on
>   xbox 1 where the correct button is Y.*

Comment: "During the beta" - I doubt the method changes on release.

Comment: @user598527 most likely you will be able to edit this in the soldier section when the game goes live

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you log in to the EA website for Battlefield and edit your persistent loadouts from there.
Then that setup will stay consistent throughout matches (i found that if you dont change it on the website, then the loadout resets from what you change it in battle and you have to redo the whole process over and over which gets frustrating).

The funny thing is, the instruction video (how to change loadout) shows you a button that should be between the server browser and server favorite buttons (in the same row on the starting page when you load the game). But its nowhere to be found oddly enough. Really wierd.