# How do I edit a loadout outside of a match?

Tags: battlefield-1

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHey2EebXzY) there is a "Customize Soldier" button at 10 second, however, I don't see it in game. Has it moved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit soldier loadout?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284600/how-to-edit-soldier-loadout)

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate flag, as the question linked as the duplicate deals with the beta of the game.  It also includes a screenshot of what the menu looked like, which is different than the one shown in the video in this post.  The video the user included with their post clearly shows a customize solider option at what looks like a main menu.

Comment: @TimmyJim: I added beta tag just to make sure. In the video I don't see any differences apart from menu background (but don't own the game): https://youtu.be/zHey2EebXzY?t=11s

Comment: See my [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288465/where-can-i-find-my-k-d-and-kill-streak-stats-in-battlefield-1). Thats the answer you are looking for

Comment: @Babidi No, actually it's not... your question is based on XP and killstreaks, this question is based on Soldier Customization.

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of BF1 you can modify your loadout during a game, or via the Battlefield companion app, and also on the battlefield website (you need to log in).
I can't find the source, but I saw that the "Customize Soldier" screen is going to come back in a future update of the game.

See [How to edit soldier loadout?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284600/how-to-edit-soldier-loadout)

Comment: From my experience, it _only_ works correctly, when you're in game and the phone on which you have companion app is connected to the same network. Otherwise the companion app just shows default loadouts and has no effect on the game. So quite different than it used to work in BF4 app.